# Displaying the attribute table with one vertical "row" in an Atlas QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, atlas, vertical

I have an attribute table in QGIS with many columns and just one feature. I want to display it in my atlas with the attributes showing vertically, otherwise it is off the page. Is there a way to do this?

Newest QGIS 3.10.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No way to pivot the inserted attribute table as of version 3.10.

You would have to do it in a label.

Simply just with the values:

[image]

Or if you need to maintain a table like look you can use HTML:

[image]

HTML table: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: That works well, Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi Laura, if the answer has solved your issue, please select is as correct using the green check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Hi Heikki,, This worked really well at fist but now has stopped working! Can't work out why, any ideas? used the first method i.e. Area (ha): [% "Area (ha)"%] but its just showing Area (ha): [Area (ha)] in the box. I've tried starting again with a new box but it just does the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the atlas preview on?

Comment: Is that in the atlas tab? generate an atlas?

Comment: It's the map button to the left of the arrows in the first picture in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265206/qgis-print-composer-preview-atlas-combo-box-limited-to-499-features

Comment: yes that is switched on

Comment: wait, I clicked it again and it all changed! Thanks so much!

Comment: That is a preview of what you will see when you export the Atlas. So you can turn the preview on and off, and go through the features.

Answer (score 3):

With a virtual layer, you can tricky make another table. The following query is for 4 fields, adjust-it as you want :

```sql
WITH t1(c1, c2, c3, c4) AS ( -- add as much as you want of field aliases
  SELECT
    ID, FIELD_NAME1, FIELD_NAME2, FIELD_NAME3 -- list here all the fields you want
  FROM YOUR_LAYER -- change with your layer name
)

SELECT c1 AS "My Pretty Field Header" FROM t1 UNION ALL
SELECT c2 FROM t1 UNION ALL
SELECT c3 FROM t1 UNION ALL
SELECT c4 FROM t1 -- add lines as much as fields and name it properly.
```

Or take a look at this code and adapt it for make a list for each fields : https://madmanwoo.gitlab.io/foss4g-python-workshop/expression_functions/#layout-example

Answer (score 0):

There's also another workaround:

1. Insert an attribute table
2. in "Main properties" / "Attributes..." select only one attribute to display
3. Repeat this process and just put one table below the other one by one